# Where can I buy the PrimeSense Carmine 1.09

Tags: rgbd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

I'm looking into purchasing the new close-range Primesense RGB-D camera but I can't seem to find it available on Amazon.com and on Ebay the prices seem outrageous to me. How much does this camera typically cost? Will they come onto the public market soon?

Cheers,
Martin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217446/where-can-i-buy-the-primesense-carmine-1.09/) by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2015-09-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CB3D](https://answers.ros.org/users/30559/cb3d/) on 2018-03-28**:
Hello Guys, we have over 1000 pieces Primsense Carime 1.09 Sensor in stock, can delivery as normal.

if any enquiry, just infor me here or send email to enquirynow@163.com

Mike Lam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Carmine 1.09 is not that new as you think :D It is already gone from the market since PrimeSense was sold to Apple.

[Cubify Sense](http://cubify.com/products/sense) seems to use the same sensor. But i didn't get it to run with OpenNI till now.

Otherwise for close range I recommend [Intel RealSense](http://click.intel.com/intel-realsense-developer-kit.html), which has even better specs. ROS support works in Beta to access RGB and Depth and Interpolated PointCloud till now.

---

Originally posted by [RodBelaFarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3527/rodbelafarin/) with karma: 235 on 2015-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1